# Find unique pairs in Sql and show corresponding date with it

Tags: sql-server

So I've been struggling with this for a day now. Lets say I have the following fields

```
Code  Code  EarliestDateL  LastDate   Status
A      B    01-01-2020    01-01-2030  Checked
B      A    01-01-2021    01-01-2030  Checked
B      A    01-01-2030    <empty>     Checked
C      A    01-01-2022    <empty>     Checked
DT     E    01-01-2022    01-01-2030  Checked
```

And as a final result I want to have this:

```
Code Code   EarliestDate  LastDate   
A     B      01-01-2020    <empty>
C     A      01-01-2022    <empty>
DT    E      01-01-2022   01-01-2030
```

The query I'm working with at the moment is as followed:

```
SELECT 
CODE_1
,CODE_2
,MIN(EARLIEST_DATE)
,CASE 
    WHEN MAX(LAST_DATE) IS NOT NULL THEN MAX(LAST_DATE)
    WHEN ISNULL(MAX(LAST_DATE),'9999-12-31') > MAX(LAST_DATE) THEN NULL
    ELSE NULL
END
FROM Table T1
WHERE T1.CODE_1 <= T1.CODE_2
OR NOT EXISTS 
        (SELECT 1 
        FROM Table T2
        WHERE (T2.CODE_2= T1.CODE_1 AND T2.CODE_1 = T1.CODE_2))
GROUP BY 
CODE_1
,CODE_2;
```

Comment: Please explain the question a bit. Why the row related to "B A.." will not come in result? What is the criteria for selecting rows in output.

Comment: What do you want to filter? Explain your expected output.

Comment: i need the Unique relation since a - b is same as b - a. And a - c is one relation etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could filter with `not exists`. To implement the logic to generate the `endDate`, an option is to use `not exists` again:

```
select 
    t.code_1,
    t.code_2,
    t.ealierstDate,
    case when exists (
        select 1 
        from mytable t1
        where 
            t1.lastDate is null
            and (
                (t1.code_1 = t.code_1 and t1.code_2 = t.code_2)
                or (t1.code_1 = t.code_2 and t1.code_2 = t.code_1)
            )
    ) then null else lastDate end lastDate   
from mytable t
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from mytable t1
    where 
        (
            (t1.code_1 = t.code_1 and t1.code_2 = t.code_2)
            or (t1.code_1 = t.code_2 and t1.code_2 = t.code_1)
        )
        and t1.ealierstDate < t.ealierstDate
)
```

Comment: This is not the result I'm expecting, the relation between A-B needs to have a LastDate <empty>. But thanks for your insights!

Comment: @EvgeniB: yes I noticed that after posting my answer... Just updated the query.